# In SharePoint 2013 where can I change the Left Navigation?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So I've been working with SharePoint 2013 recently and I really love the links that can be placed in a navigation menu on the left side. The problem is I don't like the formatting of it. I want to indent some of the links and maybe implement accordion drop downs. If someone knows where I can edit this Left Navigation and how to do some of these thanks that'd be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For indentation, that's pretty straightforward. Just click on the Edit page button in the upper left corner. In the editing context, you'll see a link at the bottom of the left hand nav that say Edit Links. Click on that link, and then add links using the + link option that appears at the bottom of the left hand nav now. Then just move links to the desired locations simply by dragging and dropping. There will be some restrictions based on the link types (for example, you won't be able to indent a link to a site/subsite below a link to a page), but for hierarchical relationships that are allowed, this will work.

If you want to make all or some of the links to subsites children of a link entry, you can create a dummy link, without a URL, and then drag and drop the links you want below that.

For the accordion menu, you'd have to code that. Here's a link to someone who's written a JQuery function for this:

http://borderingdotnet.blogspot.com/2013/04/accordion-left-navigation-for.html

I'm not endorsing the above code, to be clear, I'm only referencing it as an example of what the solution would need to be.

Comment: Thank you. I also found that if you go into "Site Settings" and then "Term Store Management" that you can look within your site and change the hierarchical relationships between the pages and by doing so you can make the left nav menu display as you want. It's also funny that you found that same site because, in the future with fewer time constraints, I was planning on attempting to implement that exact code from that web page. Thanks for the help!